# Triggering hover effect using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, jsf-1.2

I have two banners (images) which keep switching every 4 seconds. One image is clickable and the other is not. Below is the code,

```
<div class="contentdiv"> 
  <h:commandLink  action="#{myBean.firstBannerClick}" id="firstBanner" style="text-decoration:none;">
  <img src="/firstImage.jpg" width="590" height="210"  border="0" class="clickable"/> 
  </h:commandLink> 
</div>

<div class="contentdiv"> 
    <img src="/secondImage.jpg" width="590" height="210"  border="0" class="notClickable"/> 
</div>
```

**EDIT: I tried below code also**

```
$(function(){
    $('.clickable a').hover(function(){
        $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});
    },function(){
        $(this).css({'cursor':'default'});
    });
});

$(function(){
    $('.notClickable a').hover(function(){
        $(this).css({'cursor':'default'});
    },function(){
        $(this).css({'cursor':'default'});
    });
});
```

**EDIT ends here**

Below is the `CSS` used.

```
<style type="text/css">
.clickable
{
cursor: pointer;
}
.clickable a:hover
{
cursor: pointer;
}
.notClickable
{
cursor: default;
}
.notClickable a:HOVER
{
cursor: default;
}

.chrome .clickable
{
cursor: pointer;
}
.chrome .clickable a:hover
{
cursor: pointer;
}
.chrome .notClickable
{
cursor: default;
}
.chrome .notClickable a:HOVER
{
cursor: default;
}
</style>
```

When images switch, 1st image will appear as Pointer to user when he moves his cursor over the image. When a switch happens to 2nd image, and when user has not moved his cursor away from the image, 2nd image will also appear as Pointer instead of Default. Only when User moves his cursor on 2nd image, it will change as Default and then User will come to know that 2nd image is not clickable.

This problem is not seen on FF. Whereas, this is seen in Chrome and IE.

This question can be seen as continuation of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873362/cursorpointer-and-default-not-reflecting-immediately/13873459#comment19139402_13873459). Since, now the problem is specific to browsers, I raised it as a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the mouse cursor like this:

```
// Changes the cursor to an hourglass
function cursor_wait() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
}

// Returns the cursor to the default pointer
function cursor_clear() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
}
```

Comment: Inside .hover() for any "a" element, use a variable to check the state of the button.